# MyFaces continues to run in DEV mode after project stage changed to Production

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, websphere-portal

Running in Websphere Portal 7 and MyFaces 2.1.10.

The deployment descriptor for the web module in WAS shows the PROJECT_STAGE property has a value of 'Production'.

Yet when the application starts I see the MyFaces warning "Apache MyFaces-2 is running in DEVELOPMENT mode". If an error occurs in JSF I see the full stack trace on the page which indicates that it is in fact running in DEV mode.

Can the property be set somewhere else which overrides the value in the web.xml file? How can I stop DEV mode if the value in web.xml seems to be ignored?

Thanks.

Comment: Trey to clean the project and redeploy it. This should be added to deployment descriptor. <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

Comment: check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524901/how-to-configure-jsf-2-0-applications-project-stage-via-jndi-in-tomcat

Comment: May be it was set in JNDI. check the server configuration.

Comment: Thanks neni. It turned out to be JRebel switching on DEVELOPMENT mode for me.

Comment: +1 happens with me too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had setup JRebel on this project and it turns on facelet DEVELOPMENT mode. http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/features/frameworks/